# Check an application has been loaded in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to check an application is loaded or not. When one isn't loaded yet I want to display ActivityIndicator when application is loaded just display "Loaded" text. Remember, in functional programming.

```
const [loaded, isLoaded] = useState(false);

componentDidMount() {
  isLoaded(true);
}

return (
  {loaded 
    ? <Text>Loaded></Text> 
    : <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#FF324d" />}
);
```

Comment: componentDidMount() does not work in functional components.

Comment: useEffect would be the best option

Comment: What you have done is correct just change from componentDidMount to useEffect(
   () => {
       isLoaded(true);

}
,[]);  -> This much should be fine